# The question is printed twice ( after providing the right answer ) JavaScript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

What I am trying to do is ask the user to provide an answer (paper - rock - scissors).
I grab the input of the user and applied the while loop logic to check if the answer is one of the three possibilities.
The problem is that the first time the prompt pops and I provide (one of the three possibilities) it asks me again, after it asks me again and apply one of the three possibilities it works normally.

My question is why it asks twice in this case?
Thanks in advance

/*Code */

```
const Rock = "rock";
const Paper = "paper";
const Scissors = "scissors";

const userInput = () => {
  const askingQuestion =
    "Please choose between the following : Rock Paper or Scissors";
  let captureUserInput = prompt(askingQuestion).toLowerCase();
  while (
    captureUserInput !== Rock ||
    captureUserInput !== Paper ||
    captureUserInput !== Scissors
  ) {
    captureUserInput = prompt(askingQuestion);
    if (
      captureUserInput === Rock ||
      captureUserInput === Paper ||
      captureUserInput === Scissors
    ) {
      document.write(
        `Your Answer is right ! and you choose ${captureUserInput}`
      );
      break;
    }
  }
};

const computerInput = () => {
  const computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  console.log(computerChoice);
};

userInput();
computerInput();
```

Comment: your boolean logic is flawed ... `a is not 0 OR a is not 1 OR a is not 2` is ALWAYS true, since `a` can not be all three values at once ... use AND in the while loop

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. The same && goes between the if block instead of || ?

Comment: that would make it ... `a is 0 AND a is 1 AND a is 2` clearly same problem ... see ... `is` vs `is not` behave differently with AND and OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do without loop

```
const Rock = "rock";
const Paper = "paper";
const Scissors = "scissors";

const userInput = () => {
  const askingQuestion =
  "Please choose between the following : Rock Paper or Scissors";

  let captureUserInput = prompt(askingQuestion).toLowerCase();

  if (captureUserInput === Rock ||
     captureUserInput === Paper ||
     captureUserInput === Scissors) {
     console.log('valid')
   } else {
     console.log('Invalid')
     //call again recursive
     userInput()
  }
};

const computerInput = () => {
   const computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
   console.log(computerChoice);
};

 userInput();
 computerInput();
```

with this you will reduce your code and execution time

Comment: I wish put they told me I can't unless I have several points, maybe vote for my question, so I have points which allows me to mark it.